# GPT "Type device filename, or press <Enter> to exit?

Tags: partition, gdisk

I am attempting to install Arch Linux (for the hundredth time) and I recently ran across another problem. I am trying to find a list of my partitions. In order to do this I enter`gdisk`
When I do this however it returns

> Type device filename, or press  to exit:

I have attempted entering `gdisk /dev/disk1`
When I do this I get there error

> Problem opening /dev/disk1 for reading! Error is 2.

However, I am still able to mount partitions when I know the partition. I am simply trying to get a list of my partitions so I can remember which ones they are.

Any help understanding the problem would be useful.

(Off topic question: Boot loaders do not need to be installed in the first partition of root correct? Last time I installed it I put it in /boot yet I was given an error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gdisk` is throwing an error because `/dev/disk1` is only an example, not a real block device. Use `gdisk /dev/sda` if you want to work on your first drive.

`gdisk` is extradordinarily well documented on it's author's, Rod Smith, site: [Rod's Books](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/walkthrough.html).

Answer (score 4):

gdisk Error 2 means the file or device could not be found. Several other commands will list disks and partitions:

```
sudo parted -l

sudo fdisk -l

lsblk
```

As for boot loaders, where you install them depends on the boot loader and the partition table as well as computer BIOS. See the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB2) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: The Arch wiki is the most confusing thing in the world.

Comment: I wish they would just separate all the different types of installs.

Comment: @Griffin - agree the wiki could use some restructuring, but the linked article is actually very informative and well-written. I'm more of a Fedora guy myself, so haven't spent a lot of time there.

Comment: where did you get the definition for Error 2?  I have looked at the documentation and cant find what is Error 13 or 6 for that matter.